# Sobolev spaces $ H^{-1}(a,b), \ W^{1, \infty}_0(a,b) $ and $W^{-1,1}(a,b)$

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

My pde lecture defined

> $W^{1,p}_0(a,b):=clos_{\lVert \cdot \rVert_{1,p}} \mathcal{C}^\infty_c(a,b)$

For $p<\infty$ we proved that

> $W^{1,p}_0(a,b)=\{u  \in W^{1,p}(a,b), u(a)=0=u(b)\}$

where this pointwise evaluation is to be understood as the pointwise evalution of the continuous representative.

The proof doesn`t work for $p=\infty$ and in fact we were told, that the statement is not not true for this choice of p. (Though the $\subset$ inclusion should still hold, right?).

Can somebody provide an example which is not in the closure on the left?

Also, I was wondering if there is any intuition behind $W^{1, \infty}_0(a,b)$. How does this space look and how is it useful?

For $q>1$ we also defined

> $W^{-1,q}(a,b):=(W^{1,p}_0(a,b))^*$

The notation makes sense, since $W_0^{1,p}(a,b) \overset{\mathrm{d}}{\hookrightarrow} L^p(a,b)$ (compactly for $p>1$) and $L^q(a,b)\cong (L^p(a,b))^*$ for $p<\infty$.

Again, I was wondering about the case of $p=\infty$ or $q=1$. Is $W^{-1,1}(a,b)$ even defined? Is there any use or intuation behind this space?

(The notation clearly woudn´t make a lot of sense, since $L^1(a,b) \not\cong (L^\infty(a,b))^*$, but we can still think about the dual space on the right hand side).

I also have a question about the hilbert space case; I was wondering about the folowing statement in my script:

> For all $f \in H^{-1}(a,b)(:=W^{-1,2}(a,b))$ there exists a (not unique) $v_f \in L^2(a,b)$ s.t. 
>   $$\forall \ u \in H^1(a,b)(:=W^{1,2}(a,b)): \langle f, u \rangle=f(u)=\int_a^b v_f(x)u^\prime(x) \mathrm{d}x=(v_f,u)_{1,2}$$

Now, what puzzles me about this statement is the "not unique" part. For $f \in (L^2(a,b))^*$ the existence of a unique $v_f \in L^2(a,b)$ with $f(u)=(v_f, u)_{1,2}$ for all $u \in L^2(a,b)$ is implied by Riez`s representation theorem. But is $f$ not already completely characterized by $f|_{W^{1,2}_0(a,b)}$, since this space is dense in $L^2(a,b)$? Shoudn´t the $u_f$ in the theorem from my script be unique?

Thanks in advance for any answers as well as corrections of what I wrote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know, classically, that $C_0(X),$ where $X$ is locally compact, is a closed subspace of $L^{\infty}$. The exact same argument tells you that $C_0^k(X)$ is closed in the norm
$$
||f||_{k,\infty}=\sum_{j=0}^k \sum_{|\alpha|=j}||\partial^{\alpha} f||_{\infty},
$$
and this is exactly the $W^{k,\infty}$-norm. Hence, to answer your second question: $W^{k,\infty}$ is *always* a classical function space.

To answer your first question, if you take $f(x)=1_{[0,1)}-1_{[1,2]},$ then $g(x)=\int_0^{x} f(t)\textrm{d}t$ defines an element of $L^{\infty}_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ and hence, it restricts to an $L^{\infty}$ function on any bounded interval. It is also immediate, that $g(0)=0$ and $g(2)=0,$ but $g$ does not have a continuous derivative, hence does not belong to the space above with $k=1$ and $X=(0,2)$.

Comment: As for the Hilbert space case, note that, while $H^1$ *is* dense in $L^2,$ your functional might not be $L^2$-continuous. It's assumed to be $H^1$-continuous, which is somewhat easier - because it's harder for a sequence to be $H^1$-convergent.

Comment: For instance, let $\langle f,u\rangle= \int_a^b u'(x) g(x)\textrm{d}t$ for some $g\in L^2((a,b))$. This functional is clearly not $L^2$-continuous and very clearly $H^1$-continuous (setting $g=1_{[x_0,b]}$ makes this almost a pointwise evaluation functional).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What exactly do you mean by "$W^{k, \infty}$ is always a classical function space" ? As I understood the sentence before you mean that $clos_{k, \infty} \mathcal{C}^\infty_c \subset \mathcal{C}^k_c$ since the right-hand side space is closed in the $W^{k,\infty}$ norm and contains the space of which we consider the closure, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. So no matter what, its closure must consist of classical functions (i.e. continuous functions with classical derivatives as opposed to a.e.-defined functions with $L^p$-derivatives).

Comment: Btw, when I write $C_0(X),$ I refer to the space of functions vanishing at $\infty,$ not the space of functions with compact support (the latter space would not be complete).